# Find the limit using a calculator

Tags: limits

We have $u_0 = 6$ and $u_{n+1} = \dfrac{1}{2} u_n + \dfrac{1}{u_n}$. We can use our graphing calculator to make a 'web diagram' (no idea what it is called in English, and I can't find it. It sometimes resembles a spider's web).

When I use my calculator for very high values of n I get the same answer, $12.164$.

- Is this the limit?
- How would I be able to obtain this limit without the graphing calculator? Is it just the intersection with the line $y=x$?

Comment: Perhaps you have transcribed the function incorrectly. The one given converges to nothing near $12.164$ (it actually approaches $\sqrt{2}$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When $x>\sqrt{2}$, one has $\sqrt{2}<\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{x}<x$, then $u_0>u_1>\dots>\sqrt{2}$. So the series converges, say $u_n\to u$, then $u=\sqrt{2}$ by solving $\frac{u}{2}+\frac{1}{u}=u$.

(For completeness: if  $0<u_0<\sqrt{2}$, then $u_1>\sqrt{2}$, the result will be the same; If $u_0<0$, then the limit is $-\sqrt{2}$ by symmetry.)

Comment: +1 I like that you **showed** convergence (that the sequence does in fact converge to some limit $u$), and **then** revealed how to solve for the limit $u$.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the sequence $\,\{u_n\}\,$ converges to a limit $\,u\,$ ,we get from arithmetic of limits:

$$u=\frac12u+\frac1 u\implies\frac12u=\frac1u\implies u^2=2\implies u=\sqrt 2$$

Comment: Does that take into account that $u_0 = 6$?

Comment: @StighurtAndersson Yep, $u_n>0$.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't matter: it may as well be $\,u_0=1029399^{10292}\;$ . The limit, *if it exists*, still is $\,\sqrt 2\,$ .Carefully calculate the first $\;5-6\;$ elements, the sequence very rapidly converges to that value (at least beginning with $\,6\,$)

Comment: Yes, than I spotted the mistake, when I put it in my calculator I added a term $+6$. When I removed it, it gave me $\sqrt{2}$ too.

Comment: The $\ge$ under Ind. Hyp. is not correct.

Comment: I think it is, @MaMing...or else can you point at the mistake? Thanks.

Comment: By induction hypothesis, $\frac{1}{4}u_n^2 \ge \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Yes, I think I see your point @MaMing. Thanks, I shall try to edit that part.

Comment: Indeed, it was hopeless...

Comment: @DonAntonio $\frac{1}{2} u+\frac{1}{u}\ge 2\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} u\frac{1}{u}}=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Yes, I know @MaMing, but that's how you did it, not how I tried...Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9070/discussion-between-ma-ming-and-donantonio)

Comment: @DonAntonio: I completely agree, dear friend, what you say in your presentation. You're right, what you say it is true.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, the OP was *actually* iterating  $$u_n=\frac{1}{2} u_{n-1}+\frac{1}{u_{n-1}}+6$$
If this has a limit, it is found by $u=0.5u+\frac{1}{u}+6$ or $\frac{u}{2}-\frac{1}{u}-6=0$ or $\frac{u^2}{2}-6u-1=0$.

This has exactly one positive solution, namely $6+\sqrt{38}\approx 12.1644$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search, the common English term is [Cobweb Diagram](https://www.google.com/search?q=cobweb%20diagram&tbm=isch)